# How to properly terminate a POCO ServerAPplication from an Http request handler

Tags: c++, rest, poco-libraries

I am writing a small REST interface using the POCO (pocoproject.org) HttpServer class. On of the requests on the interface should be to stop the server application. However, I have not found a way to get hold of the ServerApplication's terminate method from the request handler without storing a handle to the ServerApplication in a global variable. I can get hold of the Application's instance, but it has no terminate method.

So, what is the proper way of terminating a POCO ServerApplication from a HTTP request handler?

Comment: If you're trying to exit the ServerApplication's `waitForTerminationRequest` function then you can use [Process::requestTermination](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Process.html#16197)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks M.M. the following line did the trick:

```
Poco::Process::requestTermination(Poco::Process::id());
```